# Shortcuts for integration and differentiation?

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to learn the most useful keyboard shortcuts for doing basic operations such as integration, differentiation etc in standard form. A few questions -

1. I have checked the documentation and i found shortcuts such as Esc[intt]Esc for an integral and Esc[dintt]Esc for definite integral in standard mathematical form but i can't find a short cut for a standard derivative i.e d/dx ? I am aware you can use D[] function but i would like to be able to input in standard mathematical form. Esc[dt]Esc gives me a partial derivative but i just want standard d/dx for single variable calculus.
2. If i enter a indefinite integral and i want to change this into a definite integral is there anyway i can add the upper and lower limits or do i need to re-enter the whole integral using Esc[dintt]Esc ?

Thanks
David.

Comment: `esc`-`dd`-`esc` `x` for the infinitesimal $d x$. For simple derivatives, use `'`. For example: `Sin'[x]`. However, I would strongly urge you to **not** use such typesetting shortcuts for programming purposes. They're ok for text/taking notes, etc., but I don't think it improves your speed of programming or ease of understanding the code. It certainly does make bugs and misplaced boxes hard to find/fix...

Comment: I can enter d/dx using the maths palette but i can't find a shortcut for this. There is a shortcut for partial derivative.

Comment: ah i see. You need to actually use esc-dd-esc and enter the top line then you need to use control-/ to enter the bottom line and use esc-dd-again.

Comment: rm-rf thanks. For programming i don't use this its more for elementary demos so i can use a notation people are familiar with.

Comment: As for changing an indefinite integral to definite, you just need to add the sub/super scripts with ctrl-_ for subscript and then ctrl-5 for the superscript at the same level. (usual ctrl-6 won't work)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for help.

Comment: You should take a look at Palettes and choose one of assistants (Basic Math (switch on Advanced), Writing or Classroom).

Answer (score 2):

If you're really used to traditional math notation, you can also enter and evaluate your derivatives and integrals in `TraditionalForm`. I'll illustrate this without assuming any special stylesheet settings, starting from a default notebook (this is the version 8 default, not version 9 which I dislike). It's a step-by step walkthrough, so I'll use screen shots and menu commands instead of keyboard shortcuts (the latter make it much more streamlined but harder to explain):

Let's say you want to know the derivative of $\cos(x)$.

- Start a new numbered display equation (`Format > Style > DisplayFormulaNumbered`)

> [image: 1]

- Convert the cell to `TraditionalForm` (`Cell > Convert To > TraditionalForm`)

> [image: 2]

- The `Null` can be highlighted and overwritten with our intended derivative, using <kbd>Esc</kbd>`pd`<kbd>Esc</kbd> for the $\partial$ symbol, and **the traditional notation** for $\sin(x)$ with lower case and *round parentheses*:

> [image: 3]

- Make a fraction by highlighting the numerator and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-`/`, followed by the denominator:

> [image: 4]

- Now to **evaluate** this completely traditional looking input, highlight it and select the menu item `Evaluation > Evaluate in Place`:

> [image: 5]

- The result is this:

> [image: 6]

Similarly, you can enter integrals by doing this:

> [image: 7]

where I entered the differential as <kbd>Esc</kbd>`dd`<kbd>Esc</kbd> and the integral as <kbd>Esc</kbd>`int`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Some people prefer to set up style sheets in which the `TraditionalForm` setting for displayed equations is already pre-defined, but I wanted to use the bare-bones starting point.

**Edit: Programming with `TraditionalForm`**

While I'm discussing "natural" math input, it may be worth mentioning that you can combine the above formatting with standard input format, too.

Usually, the following won't work at all:

[image: failed]

However, if I input the function body in a `TraditionalForm` equation as shown above and then **copy** it into the function, it gets wrapped by a `FormBox` which is invisible but makes the following evaluatable:

[image: works]

> [image]

OK, with the mix of brackets, this looks very wrong from a programming perspective, but I could imagine situations where this is preferable because of its "natural" readability. Here is the proof that it works:

```
dOperator[Sin[x]]

(* ==> Cos[x] Sin[x] *)
```

To create a `FormBox` in an `Input` cell to allow you to enter `TraditionalForm` math, a quick way is to type a single letter, highlight it and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-`T`. Then replace the letter with the desired formula.