# Cell sizing and labeling for $\textit{MaTeX}$ equations

Tags: cells, document-creation, matex

I am writing a book in the Wolfram CDF format and would like to improve upon the default equation typesetting of *Mathematica*.  To this end I've loaded @Szabolcs' valuable *MaTeX*, which imports $\LaTeX$ typesetting into the *Mathematica* document:

```
Needs["MaTeX`"];
ConfigureMaTeX["pdfLaTeX" -> "/usr/texbin/pdflatex"]
```

Here's a comparison between $\LaTeX$ at the top, and *Mathematica* at the bottom.  There is no question whatsoever that the aesthetic and legibility difference is profound.

[image]

Here is just one small part of an actual equation that will appear in my book:

[image]

Again:  not the slightest doubt that the $\LaTeX$ version (bottom) is vastly superior to that in *Mathematica* (top).

When I use `DisplayNumberedFormula` and cut and past an input cell into it, I get something that looks like this:

[image]

which I find particularly ugly and illegible, at least compared to $\LaTeX$.

Let me stress that I consider myself an expert $\LaTeX$ user (published many books, solution manuals, etc., with sales into the high 10s of thousands) as well as an expert *Mathematica* programmer.  I'm happy to use whichever tool leads to the best result.

Here is a sample of the rendered *Mathematica* document.  (I've left open the equation cell.)  Notice how legible is the rendered equation.

[image: Sample book page with MaTeX equation]

A number of problems arise, however:

1. The default size of the rendered *MaTeX* equation is too small, so I have to adjust the output using `ImageSize`, as shown above.  However, this option sets the *overall* size of the rendered equation, of course not the size of individual variables.  Some equations have one line, others two or more.  Is there a way to automatically set the image size so that the rendered variable (e.g., an $x$-height) is constant?
2. Of course for the final book, I double-click on the bottom half of the highlighted cell to display only the *MaTeX*-rendered equation, not its source code.  I want to be able to edit the typesetting commands and hit return and get an "output" cell of the type `NumberedEquation`.  In short, is there a way to make a special "Equation Input" cell such that its output cell (an equation) is of a type `NumberedEquation` which retains its Tag and other properties as I type in variations of the source *MaTeX* code?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your edit just demonstrates a lack of understanding of typesetting Mathematica equations for *output*. At the end of the day people should use whatever code enables them to get the job done the way they prefer. If you know LaTeX and prefer that then of course use that but the example above is an apples and oranges comparison.

Comment: Mike Honeychurch:  My book (**Pattern Classification**, 3rd ed.) is meant to be read and understood by students.  The book has nothing to do with using "whatever code enables them to get the job done."  Students don't *care* what typesetting I use... they need to read and understand the text and especially the equations.  If there is some *Mathematica* display setting that yields high-quality equation typesetting, then I'm eager to learn of it.  But all *Mathematica*'s defaults are woefully inadequate, as my examples above (and many others) prove.  I know well both $\LaTeX$ and *Mathematica*.

Comment: "whatever code enables them to get the job done" was clearly made in the context of typesetting. In other words I am agreeing with you that others (incl. students) do not care what typesetting methods you use, they just want to read the text. So whatever code enables them (authors) to get the job (typesetting) done is okay. As I have partially said in comments to my deleted answer, if you know LaTex then it is highly likely that it would be a better tool to use. It will most likely be more efficient than using Mathematica. But to claim that something similar cannot be done in Mma misrepresents

Comment: I don't know if this is of use to you, but I always use a version-8 style sheet in which `TraditionalForm` looks really traditional (as close to $\LaTeX$ as it  ever was). See my question [Inconsistent display of TraditionalForm in version 9](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16154/245) for ways to get this older styling back. To enter displayed equations, I follow some variation of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18986/245). I usually create PDFs of notebooks and distribute them along with the source. However, PDF export is never great (e.g., no reference links).

Comment: MaTeX has the options `FontSize` and `Magnification` both of which can be used to achieve consistent resizing of text.

Comment: Please do make sure that you use version 1.2.0 of MaTeX, released just a few days ago!  It corrects some subtle sizing bugs.  Check it with ``MaTeX`Developer`$Version``.

Answer (score 9):

this is (now a very long) comment not an answer.

The objective is to write a book using Mathematica. Within the book equations are *generated* from LaTex rather than typeset directly using Mathematica. By definition if this was to be done entirely using Mathematica, the equation typesetting would not be done in an input cell. It would be done either in one of the bundled styles that have been designed for rendering typeset equations, such as "DisplayFormulaNumbered", or a custom cell style with similar properties. Comparing output to input is a disingenuous apples/oranges comparison. If you use Mathematica correctly for creating equations then you can create a book with typesetting like this:

[image]

Now this may still be unsatisfactory to some people (who may prefer other methods such as LaTex) but it is also quite different to the apples/oranges comparison presented in the question.

So the first part of the question, when modified to compare like to like, ultimately gets down to what best enables you to do the job (i.e. typesetting a document) efficiently and meet your aesthetic preferences.

The second part of the question was a required code modification so that you can evaluate a cell and have the output in a numbered equation style rather than output. It is disappointing when contributors here devote time to provide an answer, demonstrate the answer, and have it ignored.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit to reply in more detail to first comment.**

My deleted answer to part 2 was just that. Part 2 asks *"In short, is there a way to make a special "Equation Input" cell such that its output cell (an equation) is of a type NumberedEquation"*. In other words this is not asking about typesetting it is asking about changing a generated cell style. My deleted answer provided a solution.

In your comment you say "*Your retracted code that I saw before did not (as far as I could tell) lead to reasonably nice equations, such as in 11.48, above.*"

As per first edited sentence the answer was a solution to changing a generated cell it was not a solution to typesetting. If you want to typeset in Mathematica you do not type into input, evaluate input, and display the output (and probably hide the input) in your document. That is a fundamentally wrong way to go about typesetting a document ("natively") in Mathematica. If you want to use the "MaTex" package then yes, that is what you need to do, but if you want to typeset directly in Mathematica then that is the last thing you want to do.

Comment: It is true, I am not an expert in using *Mathematica* for *display* and am eager to learn.  (My book will be an eBook, so the tools for typesetting to paper are not relevant.)  Your retracted code that I saw before did not (as far as I could tell) lead to reasonably nice equations, such as in 11.48, above.  Would it have been that nice?  If so, point me to such styles.  Regardless, one must ask:  Why did expert szabolcs (reputation 90k) feel the need to create *MaTeX* if the quality of *Mma* output was high like you say?  I'm not alone in wanting improvements over *Mathematica* typesetting.

Comment: The objective is absolutely positively *NOT* to write a book using *Mathematica*!  Not at all.  It is instead to create a document (paper or eDocument) that will best inform students and experts alike, whatever the creation tool.  If *MS Word* led to better typesetting, layout, control, etc., I would use it.  Likewise *FrameMaker*.  Or any other software.  I want to use *Mma* for dynamic figures created by computer science expert (and friend) Stephen Wolfram, but wish to preserve the superb typography developed by typographical sophisticate (and friend) Donald Knuth.

Comment: Maybe szabolcs already knows LaTeX -- you need to ask him. For anyone who knows LaTeX then I don't see any reason to switch. The point is that, and I realise this is subjective, pretty good equation rendering can be done in Mathematica. I am not saying it *has to be done* in Mma I am saying it can be done if you choose to. ... and reiterate that the examples in the question are apples and oranges

Comment: Mike:  I like the equations you have posted.  How do I create these in an electronic *Mathematica* document?  I couldn't see that your earlier code would accomplish that, but maybe I'm wrong.  [Surely szabolcs knows well both *Mathematica* and $\LaTeX$.]

Comment: @DavidG.Stork please see my edit. Szabolcs is a Mma expert but I cannot speak to why he made the package other than if he was already expert in LaTeX then it would make sense to typeset in LaTeX. You need to ask him. I do not know LaTeX but the impression I get is that the rendering can be done a whole lot easier (it can still be done in Mma but generally it can often take a fair bit of tweeking). You should not be using input cells. You should be using e.g. DisplayFormulaNumbered and then creating an inline cell. Do that and cut and paste one of your input cell eqns as a first try

Comment: Mike:  I did as you recommend and got the image in my original question... not nearly as clear or lovely as your eq. 11.48 and your following material.  How do I get output as nice as yours?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have to go now. I will undelete my answer. If you are an expert with LaTex then it is far more efficient for you to typeset in LaTeX and my initial queries have been answered. But for those who do not know LaTeX they should be made aware that good typesetting can be done in Mma. Please try my code with your package. It should automatically number your MaTeX generated equations and render them in the appropriate cell style as per your requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36298/discussion-between-david-g-stork-and-mike-honeychurch).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I need to go. we were going out to lunch. I will post something later today or tomorrow to go through steps required to get "proper" typesetting

Answer (score 6):

I guess my questions are 1) why you are not doing the typesetting in Mathematica; 2) for those of us unfamiliar with MaTeX are the equations rendered as vectors or bitmap or what?

Here is a solution to part 2 of your question.

Step 1. Make a new style. I am going to call it "MaTeX". In this style you will use the `CellEpilog` option to change the output cell to your desired style.

```
CellPrint@
 Cell[StyleData["MaTeX", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Input"]],
  MenuSortingValue -> 1510,
  CellEpilog :> (SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, GeneratedCell]; 
    FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationCell[], "Style", 
     "DisplayFormulaNumbered"])
  ]
```

Step 2. Add this style to a private style sheet or for regular work create a new stylesheet with this cell.

Step 3. Use this style as per GIF below. In the GIF I first evaluate an input cell and it creates an output cell. Then I repeat but first change the cell style to "MaTeX" (which occurs offscreen) and then you see that the output is a "DisplayFormulaNumbered" cell.

[image]

Comment: Mike Honeychurch:  As I wrote, I "...would like to improve upon the default equation typesetting of *Mathematica*."  Type a complex formula with lots of integral signs, summations, powers (of powers), factorials, upper- and lower-case Greek letters and such.  They look ugly in *Mathematica* but gorgeous in $\LaTeX$.  Your simple examples of "1 + 1" are not nearly sophisticated enough to show the graphic limitations of *Mathematica*.  Even my simple example, above, shows the superior legibility of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork beauty is in the eye of the beholder. You don't provide any examples of Mathematica being deficient in typesetting. Certainly the example doesn't appear to be an improvement on Mathematica (IMO). I've typeset probably 2200 pages of Mathematica for publication over the years, maybe more, and had not had issues with the aesthetics. ...I should add that if we are talking about ease of typesetting then that would be a different issue. Anyway is the above a solution for you? The example of 1+1 is solely to generate your desired output cell type. I thought that would be obvious

Answer (score 6):

I did not notice this post until today.

MaTeX has two options for setting the size of the output:

- `Magnification` just scales everything (i.e. the PDF file output by LaTeX) proportionally.
- `FontSize` passes the font size to LaTeX and thus gives access to the special variants for each point size.

When I work with MaTeX, I tend to set all its option to my preferred value at the start of the session, like this

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, Magnification -> ..., FontSize -> ..., ...]
```

I.e. just what @martin mentioned.

Mathematica's default font size is 14, but MaTeX's is 12.  So you may want to start with `FontSize -> 14` and leave `Magnification` at the default value of 1.

Here's a little demo of how `FontSize` and magnification differ:

```
MaTeX["\\int_0^\\infty e^{-x}\\, dx", FontSize -> 20, Magnification -> 1]
```

[image]

```
MaTeX["\\int_0^\\infty e^{-x}\\, dx", FontSize -> 10, Magnification -> 2]
```

[image]

```
MaTeX["\\int_0^\\infty e^{-x}\\, dx", FontSize -> 5, Magnification -> 4]
```

[image]

5 pt is designed for legibility at small sizes and looks awkward magnified 4 times.  20 pt is designed for beauty when displayed at its actual size.

---

Since version 1.2.0 it also has the options `ContentPadding` and `LineSpacing` which effectively control vertical margins and shouldn't be necessary most of the time.  Here's a small demo:

```
f = Framed[#, ContentPadding -> False, FrameMargins -> None, 
    FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1]] &;

f /@ MaTeX /@ {"x", "y", "M"}
```

[image]

```
f /@ (MaTeX[#, LineSpacing -> {1, 0}] &) /@ {"x", "y", "M"}
```

[image]

```
f /@ (MaTeX[#, ContentPadding -> False] &) /@ {"x", "y", "M"}
```

[image]

Both options follow the standard Mathematica usage.  `LineSpacing -> {m,a}` makes the line height be `m*fontsize + a`, in points.  `ContentPadding -> True` enforces a minimal height equal to one line heigh for the output.  A display style output is usually taller than one line height, so it won't make a difference there.

---

Here's a little modification to @Mike's special cell style.

```
CellPrint@
 Cell[StyleData["MaTeX", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Program"]], 
  MenuSortingValue -> 1510, 
  CellEpilog :> (SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, GeneratedCell];
    FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationCell[], "Style", 
     "DisplayFormulaNumbered"]),
  Evaluatable -> True, 
  CellEvaluationFunction -> (MaTeX[
      First[FrontEndExecute[ExportPacket[Cell[#1], "InputText"]]]] &),
   CellFrameLabels -> {{None, "MaTeX"}, {None, None}}, 
  CellGroupingRules -> "InputGrouping"]
```

Sorry about the messy code formatting.   This is a special evaluatable input cell that renders LaTeX code:

[image]

You could probably modify this to suit your need better.  One advantage is that there's no need to type `\\` all the time anymore.  A single `\` will be fine.

---

Finally, I have to give a few warnings, as this is not really the use case I anticipated for MaTeX.  I made MaTeX because I wanted to have more beautiful labels in publication figures.  But I never meant it to be used for in-notebook display.  There will be a few disadvantages if you do this.

1. MaTeX returns the result as vector graphics.  This takes up considerably more space than the text equivalent.

   ```
   expr = HoldForm[Integrate[Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]

   ByteCount /@ {expr, MaTeX[expr]}

   (* {304, 24328} *)
   ```
2. MaTeX's output is really meant for print or for PDF viewers, which tend to render vector graphics with quite a lot of care.  *Font glyphs* are always rendered differently by computers than other vector drawings. Text rendering is special and it is optimized for legibility.  This is going to be lost with MaTeX because it converts everything to simple curves.  If you use a "retina" display, you will not be able to notice this.  But many of your readers will have low resolution screens, and to them the MaTeX output will look more "blurry" than other text.

   My personal opinion about this is that if the formulas are displayed in a large enough size (and if there aren't too many of them), then LaTeX's superior typesetting outweighs the disadvantage of the blurriness.  But it's something to be aware of.
3. MaTeX takes great care to preserve the baseline.  Thus mixing MaTeX output with text should be okay in theory ... it looks like this in large size.

   [image]

   But it turns out that the front end aggressively rounds everything to integer screen pixels early in the display pipeline, and this causes misalignments when displaying things at standard sizes:

   [image]

   So in practice it won't be possible to mix MaTeX output with standard text and still make it look good.

All in all, I would be very careful with using too much MaTeX in a CDF document.  In figures meant for print/PDF I use it all the type.  If I had to use it in CDF, I would restrict it to a few display formulas only, and I would be very careful to keep everything legible at lower resolution screens.

Comment: Szabolcs:  Thanks so much (+1), and especially thanks for creating *MaTeX*.

Comment: @David I hope you'll find it useful.  I updated the post a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

You could set it up it manually:

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}"}, 
Magnification -> 1.5];

    MaTeX["\\begin{tabular}{>{\\raggedright}m{12cm} c}
 $\\displaystyle\\mbox{}\ \\int\\limits_{x = \
-\\infty}^\\infty\\!\\!\\! |f(x)|^2 dx = \\dfrac{1}{2\\pi} \
\\int\\limits_{\\omega = -\\infty}^\\infty\\!\\!\\! |F(\\omega)|^2 \
d\\omega$ 
 &\\small{(1.1)}
 \\\\\\\\
 $\\text{This is some text.}$
 \\\\\\
 \\\\\\
 $\\displaystyle\\mbox{}\ p(\\mathcal{D}|\\theta)=\\prod\\limits_{k = \
1}^{n}\\dfrac{1}{(2\\pi)^{d/2}|\\Sigma|^{1/2}} \
\\operatorname{Exp}[(x_k-\\theta)^{t}\\Sigma^{-1}(x_k-\\theta)]$ 
 &\\small{(1.2)}
 \\end{tabular}"]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks so much!  I think Wolfram Research should make something like MaTeX the default within *Mathematica*.  No reason to retain the ugly mathematical typesetting!